# Bootstrap 4 navbar with large image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I need to add a large image (240px height) to a bootstrap 4 navbar. The branding text and the navigation links should be aligned to the bottom of the image.

I tried adding align-bottom, using different divs, etc. but didn't managed to get the links down to the bottom.

The last resort would be to add a padding-top (or margin-top) with the height of the image. But I want to avoid this since the image may change it's size depending on the device.

Any help?

Here is the demo code: https://jsfiddle.net/8n2oxtwt/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Navbar Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">

  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://cdn.stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/DOHH1Q2PPE.jpg" height="240px"> Test</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample02" aria-controls="navbarsExample02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample02">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-md-0">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search">
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

      <main role="main">
        <div class="jumbotron">
          <div class="col-sm-8 mx-auto">
            <h1>Navbar examples</h1>
            <p>This example is a quick exercise to illustrate how the navbar and its contents work. Some navbars extend the width of the viewport, others are confined within a <code>.container</code>. For positioning of navbars, checkout the <a href="../navbar-top/">top</a> and <a href="../navbar-top-fixed/">fixed top</a> examples.</p>
            <p>At the smallest breakpoint, the collapse plugin is used to hide the links and show a menu button to toggle the collapsed content.</p>
            <p>
              <a class="btn btn-primary" href="../../components/navbar/" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you want the img to be link(test link)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `align-items-end` class on the navbar, and `align-bottom` on the navbar-brand...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark align-items-end">
    <a href="#"><img src="https://cdn.stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/DOHH1Q2PPE.jpg" height="240px"> <span class="navbar-brand align-bottom pb-2">Test</span></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExample02" aria-controls="navbarsExample02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExample02">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/3YGNrRgBO9

Answer (score 0):

Use     `align-items: flex-end;` on nav element

```
.navbar.navbar-expand {
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

And change your `navbar-brand` like this

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#" style="display: flex;align-items: flex-end;">
    <img src="https://cdn.stocksnap.io/img-thumbs/960w/DOHH1Q2PPE.jpg" height="240px">
    <span> Test</span>
</a>
```